# What is the connection between Shabat and being set free from slavery of Mitzrayim?

Tags: shabbat, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, yetziat-mitzrayim

In [Shemot 20:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm#10) it is said the Shabat is important because HaShem creation caused 6 days and HaShem rested on the seventh. That one seems logical, because of this we also work 6 days and then keep the Shabat.

But in [Devarim 5:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0505.htm#14) it says that the Shabat is important because HaShem set us free from slavery.

But what is the connection between the Shabat and being took out or freed from the slavery of Mitzrayim? How is being set free be the reason for keeping the Shabat?

Comment: It doesn't say that's why Shabat is important. It says that's why God commanded us to keep Shabat.

Comment: The reason why is because we are commanded not to do slave work on Shabbat. God gave us Shabbat so we would be free from work of the slaves one day a week. This is why it says in Shemot 20:9 "six days you should serve". Same word is used. a slave or slavery. This is the whole point of Shabbat basically.

Comment: Supplementing @AleksandrSigalov's above comment, I heard from a notable rav that it is no coincidence that the 1st "communal" mitzvah was related to time management (sanctifying the new month.) While we were slaves we were unable to manage our own time. As free people we could, but we could also abuse that time. Thus, G-d commands us to set aside time for G-d. Similar concept would apply to Shabbat, as they are related.

Answer (score 1):

In many Mitzvos we are told to do it since Hashem took us out of Mitzraim. This is not a direct train for this particular Mitzva but it is a region why we must adhere to Hashem. We are His slaves now.

However, being that this comes in the place of the earlier 'In six days...' this suggests that it is in some way a reasoning for the Mitzva.

Shabbos is our commemoration of Hashem creating the world. Coming out of Mitzraim was when we got to know Hashem. The main reason we believe in Hashem is because of the exodus, more than creation arguments. Therefore, it is the taking us out of Mitzraim that confirmed to us that He created the world.

Comment: The [Meshech Chochma](https://goo.gl/r7KiVc) gives a similar explanation: One could have thought that Shabbat is relevant for people of all nations, since its main point is that Hashem created the world, and that He controls it and leads it. Even so, we find that Shabbat is relevant only for Israel. But who can really testify that Hashem created this world and controls it? Only those who He has saved, and led out of Egypt with great miracles, etc. So there's a meaningful connection between the exodus and the principle behind the observance of Shabbat.